# Можите описать, в кратце, основные ветки репозитория Google Git for Android?

Tags: android

Я никак не могу опредилиться где и какая ветвь за что отвечает. Например /android/device - это драйвера или скрипты сборки? Или что это вообще? Ну не драйвера точно, драйвера на сайте производителя.
Пожайлуста можете дать определение основных веток Git for Android? Буду очень признателен, спасибо

Ветви:
device
platform
kernel
...

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть исходники Lineage OS, также есть список версий:
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/tree/lineage-15.0

P.s и я думаю, почему в Google Git так не сделают? Раскидали файлы, а потом собирай

Comment: поле «ответ» предназначено для ответов на заданный вопос. дополнения к вопросу вносите, пожалуйста, прямо в текст вопроса (нажав ниже него ссылку «править»).

Comment: В исходниках Google есть все [то же самое](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/). Выбираете нужную версию Android слева и все